# Integrating WSO2 EMM and System Service Application

Tags: wso2

I want to install **System Service application**, But In WSO2 documentation, It has written that I need to sign the application via **Device Firmware Signing key**.

What is the meaning of this line [Device Firmware Signing key] and also how to get the System application signed by Device Vendor?

Can't Understand how to install this System Service Application.

Comment: Ok, I Understand, I have two options to Sign the application : either to purchase the vendor certificate to sign the application or to install the application as system application by making the device as root? Am I correct...